# find: paths must precede expression: find

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, chmod

Running the following find:

```
find . -exec chown apache:janderson {} \; find . -type f -exec chmod 0664 && find . -type d -exec chmod 0775 {} \;
```

But it's generating this error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: find
```

How do I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to run find 3 times?  Add a separator:

```
find . -exec chown apache:janderson {} \; && 
    find . -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \; && 
    find . -type d -exec chmod 0775 {} \;
```

You are missing the `&&` between the first and second `find` calls.  The `;` does not act as a separator, but as an argument to find which serves to terminate the `exec`.